# How many twin primes are of the form $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

The first pair is $(3,5)$ for $n=2$. Is there any other pair beside this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. The primes belonging to one of them is called a Mersenne prime. If you search it you can probably find lots about them on the internet. More than an answer on this site can contain. But there may of course be plenty of answers dealing with them if you search on the site.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed you said **twins**, then no there aren't any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are no more. A number of the form $2^n-1$ can only be prime if $n$ is prime (although there are prime $n$ which doesn't work, like $n = 11$, so $2^{11}-1$ is not prime), while a number of the form $2^n+1$ can only be prime if $n$ is a power of $2$ (again, there are power-of-two's which do not work, like $32$, so $2^{2^{5}} + 1$ is not prime). These two notions coincide only for $n = 2$.

**Proofs:**
Let $n$ be a composite number, say $n = pq$ for some $p, q\geq 2$. Then we have
$$
2^n-1 = 2^{pq}-1 = (2^p-1)(2^{(q-1)p} + 2^{(q-2)p} + \cdots + 2^p + 1)
$$
That this is composite follows from $p, q\geq 2$, which makes both of the above factors greater than $1$.

If $n$ is not a power of $2$, then $n = 2^mk$ where $k\geq 3$ is odd and $m\geq 0$. This gives us
$$
2^n + 1 = 2^{2^mk} + 1 = (2^{2^m} + 1)(2^{2^m(k-1)} - 2^{2^m(k-2)} + 2^{2^m(k-3)} - \cdots - 2^{2^m} + 1)
$$
which is necessarily composite, again because $k\geq 3$ so both factors are greater than $1$ ($k$ being odd is exactly what makes the signs work out so that you get $+1$ and not $-1$ at the end).

Answer (score 3):

For Fermat primes, we need $n$ to be a power of $2$, for Mersenne primes, we need $n$ prime. The only possible common candidate occurs for $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is another proof that's similar to the proof that there are no prime triples other than $3,5,7:$

Note that one of $k,k+1,k+2$ is divisible by $3.$ Consider $k=2^n-1.$ Clearly $k+1$ is not divisible by $3$ since $k+1=2^n$ is a power of $2.$ So $2^n-1$ or $2^n+1$ must be divisible by $3.$